# iOS Push Notifications PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, php, ios, apple-push-notifications, phonegap

I am working on a app project for iOS devices that requires push notifications.
Is there a good and up to date tutorial on how to do this?
I thought that I could create a php script and call it via cronjob every 15 minutes which will trigger the push notifications, might that be possible?

**Edit**
1. Created index.js

```
// Add to index.js or the first page that loads with your app.
// For Intel XDK and please add this to your app.js.

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  // Enable to debug issues.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };

  window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit("********************appid")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();

  // Call syncHashedEmail anywhere in your app if you have the user's email.
  // This improves the effectiveness of OneSignal's "best-time" notification scheduling feature.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.syncHashedEmail(userEmail);
}, false);
```

2. Added Code to config.xml

   `<gap:plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.1.1" source="npm" />
   <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
   <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
   <!-- Can omit if not targetting Windows Phone -->
   <preference name="windows-appx-target" value="8.1-phone" />
   <preference name="WindowsToastCapable" value="true" />`
3. Added `<script src="js/index.js"></script>` to my index.html
4. If i open up my app I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined`

Comment: This may help you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Incase, if you want to try thridparty services, Go for oneSignal or someother services which makes your job less

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented OneSignal, now I got a JS Error saying: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined`